# Перенос элементов div на новую строку если ширина ограничена через max-width

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно перенести div блоки на новую строку при этом ширина блока должна стать минимально возможной

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
</div>
```

В div элементах может быть не только текст, но например картинки небольшого размера и поэтому мне нужно проделать это именно с div

На картинке видно что блок растягивается до 500 px и остается лишнее пространство выделенное желтым
[image: показано лишнее пространство]

Вроде бы задача не сложная но как решить ее не пойму буду рад любой идее, за ранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Обозначьте вертикальное выравнивание:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: То что вы написали вообще мне не подходит, данный способ просто располагает элементы друг под другом, а мне надо чтобы элементы шли в строку друг за другом, до ограничения ширины блока wrapper и переносились, но при переносе учитывалась ширина самой длинной строки и блок wrapper по итогу оставался этой ширины, если смотреть на картинку которую я прикрепил то без области где я нарисовал желтый квадрат

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с помощью JS

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper')
let chWidth, wrpWidth = 0, maxWidth = 500

wrapper.forEach(wrp => {
  const chwrp = wrp.childNodes
  chwrp.forEach(ch => {
    if (ch.offsetWidth) {
      chWidth = ch.getBoundingClientRect().width;
      if ((wrpWidth + chWidth) < maxWidth) {
        wrpWidth += chWidth
      }
    }
  })
  wrp.style.width = wrpWidth+'px'
})

console.log('sumWidth: '+wrpWidth)
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Идея просто отличная, но есть одно но если самая длинная не первая строка это перестает работать, так что я усовершенствовал ваш вариант

Answer (score 0):

Вот идеальное решение для этой задачи

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
let chWidth,
  wrpWidth = 0,
  maxWidth = 500;

const widthArr = []

Array.from(wrapper.children).forEach((ch) => {
  chWidth = ch.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  if (wrpWidth + chWidth < maxWidth) {
    wrpWidth += chWidth;
  } else {
    widthArr.push(wrpWidth)
    wrpWidth = chWidth
  }
});

wrpWidth = Math.max(...widthArr);

wrapper.style.width = wrpWidth + "px";
console.log("sumWidth: " + wrpWidth);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text1111111111111111111111</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
  <div>|-text rtwasd text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]